# Parse through a txt document using vscode extension api

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to write a vscode extension where I can open a txt file, and parse through the contents of that txt file line by line, and be able to search for specific key words from each line.  I've been looking at the TextDocument in the vscode api, but I'm a little confused on implementing it.

How can I parse through a txt document line by line?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const { activeTextEditor } = vscode.window;
if (!activeTextEditor) return;
const lines = activeTextEditor.document.getText().split('\n');
for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const line = lines[i];
    console.log(i, line);
}
```

Comment: Usually better to use `document.lineAt` instead as it properly handles different line ending styles. For example: `for (let i = 0; i < activeTextEditor.document.lineCount; ++i) {  const line = activeTextEditor.document.lineAt(i); ...  } `